# When I import an array from another file, do I take just the data from it or need to "build" the array with how the original file build it?

Tags: python, arrays, import

Sorry if the question is not well formulated, will reformulated if necessary.

I have a file with an array that I filled with data from an online json db, I imported this array to another file to use its data.

```
#file1
response = urlopen(url1)
a=[]
data = json.loads(response.read())
for i in range(len(data)):
    a.append(data[i]['name'])
    i+=1
```

```
#file2
from file1 import a

'''do something with "a"'''
```

Does importing the array means I'm filling the array each time I call it in file2?
If that is the case, what can I do to just keep the data from the array without "building" it each time I call it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you saved a to a file, then read a -- you will not need to rebuild a -- you can just open it.  For example, here's one way to open a text file and get the text from the file:

```
# set a variable to be the open file
OpenFile = open(file_path, "r")  

# set a variable to be everything read from the file, then you can act on that variable
file_guts = OpenFile.read()
```

Comment: So is the only way to actually save the data from the array to use whenever I want is to move it to a text file and make a function to take from it?

Comment: You don't need to save it if you are going to use the data right away -- you can just keep the data in RAM.  But if you want to use the data any time you want, then yes, do save it.  You then have a wide array of choices for how to save the data.  You may want to download the original json file, or save to .csv file, or save the info to a MySQL database, etc.

Answer (score 1):

From the Python docs on the Modules section - [link](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html) - you can read:

```
When you run a Python module with
python fibo.py <arguments>
the code in the module will be executed, just as if you imported it
```

This means that importing a module has the same behavior as running it as a regular Python script, unless you use the `__name__` as mentioned right after this quotation.

Also, if you think about it, you are opening something, reading from it, and then doing some operations. How can you be sure that the content you are now reading from is the same as the one you had read the first time?

Comment: So is the only way to actually save the data from the array to use whenever I want is to move it to a text file and make a function to take from it?

Comment: @AMM Yes that is the case for pretty much everything, if a program exits and it doesn't save the contents of whatever it was doing to disk (e.g. in a text file), then their gone.
However it is possible to communicate between programs without resorting to using the disk, which is using pipes in Linux ([brief overview of pipelines from Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pipeline_(Unix))) and you can even create your own named pipes to be able to communicate between several different processes ([brief overview of named pipes from Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Named_pipe)).